# c++ int in class gets set to value, seemingly out of nowhere

Tags: c++, function, int

The `int winner` should be set to 2 under certain conditions but it's somehow being set to a variety of higher values, most commonly 6. I have no idea how this is happening, as there is no other function in my class that affects `winner`, and the variable isn't even mentioned anywhere else in the program. What is most confusing to me is that I have an almost identical function (`P2Move()`) that is literally identical in how it sets the `winner` variable to `P1Move()`, and that function runs perfectly.

Some info: The class this is part of is called Board, which acts as a checkerboard array made up of Square class objects.

Below is the function causing the problem. Near the bottom, the statement `else if((canTake.size()==0)&&(canMove.size()==0)) {Board::winner = 2;}` causes the problem. Everything else seems to work when I remove the problematic part from the function, but I need that part to work in order to submit the final project.

```
void Board::P1Move()
{
    P1pieces = 0;
    std::vector <Move> canMove;
    std::vector <Move> canTake;

    for(int j = 0; j < bSize; j++)
    { //Start of j loop.
        for(int i = 0; i < bSize; i++)
        { //Start of i loop.
            Square sq = board[i][j];
            bool cTakeL = canTakeL(i,j);
            bool cTakeR = canTakeR(i,j);
            bool cMoveL = canMoveL(i,j);
            bool cMoveR = canMoveR(i,j);

            if(board[i][j].getPl() == P1)
            {
                P1pieces++;
                if(cTakeL)
                {
                    Move a = Move(sq.getIndex(),board[i-2][j+2].getIndex(),board[i-1][j+1].getIndex(),0);
                    canTake.push_back(a);
                }
                if(cTakeR)
                {
                    Move b = Move(sq.getIndex(),board[i+2][j+2].getIndex(),board[i+1][j+1].getIndex(),0);
                    canTake.push_back(b);
                }
                if(cMoveL)
                {
                    Move c = Move(sq.getIndex(),board[i-1][j+1].getIndex(),0,0);
                    canMove.push_back(c);
                }
                if(cMoveR)
                {
                    Move d = Move(sq.getIndex(),board[i+1][j+1].getIndex(),0,0);
                    setWinner(d.getSpos());
                    canMove.push_back(d);
                }
            }
        } //End of i loop.
    } //End of j loop.

    if(canTake.size()!=0)
    {
        time_t t;
        time(&t);
        srand(t);
        int moveNum = rand()%canTake.size();
        std::string output = "p1 ";
        Move out = canTake.at(moveNum);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for(int y = 0; y < bSize; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < bSize; x++)
            {
                if(board[x][y].getIndex()==out.getSpos())
                {
                    i = x;
                    j = y;
                }
            }
        }
        if(board[i-2][j+2].getIndex()==out.getEndPos())
        {
            board[i-2][j+2].setOcc(true);
            board[i-2][j+2].setPl(P1);
            board[i-1][j+1].setOcc(false);
            board[i-1][j+1].setPl(NA);
        }
        else if(board[i+2][j+2].getIndex()==out.getEndPos())
        {
            board[i+2][j+2].setOcc(true);
            board[i+2][j+2].setPl(P1);
            board[i+1][j+1].setOcc(false);
            board[i+1][j+1].setPl(NA);
        }
        output = output + out.toString();
        setCmove(output);
        board[i][j].setOcc(false);
        board[i][j].setPl(NA);
    }
    else if(canMove.size()!=0)
    {
        time_t t;
        time(&t);
        srand(t);
        int moveNum = rand()%canMove.size();
        std::string output = "p1 ";
        Move out = canMove.at(moveNum);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for(int y = 0; y < bSize; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < bSize; x++)
            {
                if(board[x][y].getIndex()==out.getSpos())
                {
                    i = x;
                    j = y;
                }
            }
        }
        if(board[i-1][j+1].getIndex()==out.getEndPos())
        {
            board[i-1][j+1].setOcc(true);
            board[i-1][j+1].setPl(P1);
        }
        else if(board[i+1][j+1].getIndex()==out.getEndPos())
        {
            board[i+1][j+1].setOcc(true);
            board[i+1][j+1].setPl(P1);
        }
        output = output + out.toString();
        setCmove(output);
        board[i][j].setOcc(false);
        board[i][j].setPl(NA);
    }
    else if((canTake.size()==0)&&(canMove.size()==0))
    {
        Board::winner = 2;
    }
    P1pieces = canTake.size() + canMove.size();
}
```

Comment: Large functions are harder to read, regarding your question, please produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Most probably you have another function does an out of bound access and modify the winner value. Did you run any linter/code checker. You can try for instance: https://drmemory.org/. You can also put a breakpoint on the address or winner data and see which part of the code changes it.

Comment: It looks like you potentially index outside the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with `std::vector`, which is a good thing. (Too much beginner "C++" code uses C arrays.) The `vector` class template allows for a pretty easy way to find out if and where you might have an out-of-bounds access (as suggested in the comments):

Instead of accessing vector elements using `operator[]`, change your code to use the [`.at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) member function. `.at()` is bounds-checking, and will throw an exception if you access out-of-bounds (instead of silently breaking your program).

In production code, `operator[]` is usually preferred as omitting the bounds check is more efficient. But while learning, `.at()` can help you quite a bit.

Also, getting in the habit of using code checkers like  [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or the [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) macro to check your assumptions is a good thing, even when you got past the point where you wouldn't use `.at()` anymore.

Comment: While this works in a pinch, you may want to first check if the debug mode of your compiler has bounds checks on `operator[ ]`. An out of bounds error in `operator[ ]` has undefined behavior. Debug builds may use that liberty to do a bounds check, in which case you don't need two different versions of your code. E.g. Visual Studio can do this.

Comment: @MSalters: I generally work with what the standard gives me, and stay way clear of anything added by some version of some compiler on some platform if you use the right compiler options and do the correct sacrifice rites at the correct phase of the moon. ;-)